# GitHub Gist access granularity read/write API

Tags: github, access-token, github-api, gist

Can I create an access token in GitHub so it can only create gists (write access) but it cannot read the created ones?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that's not possible.

Did you read the page about [authentication for the Gist API](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#authentication)?

Quote from the link:

> ### Authentication
>
> You can read public gists and create them for anonymous users without
>   a token; however, to read or write gists on a user's behalf the **gist**
>   [OAuth scope](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-integrations/setting-up-and-registering-oauth-apps/about-scopes-for-oauth-apps/) is required.

So you can revoke **write** access to gists, but not **read** access.

When you create a new gist via the API, you can [make it public or secret](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#create-a-gist).
*(see [Types of gists](https://help.github.com/articles/about-gists/#types-of-gists))*

But even secret gists are not really secret, anyone who knows the URL can access them.
Plus, you need to authenticate in order to **create** gists, and when you're authenticated, [you can list **all** of a user's gists](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#list-a-users-gists) (including the secret ones).